# Multiple tours on one page with intro.js (rintrojs) in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, intro.js

I would like to have multiple tours on one page of a Shiny app using rintrojs. Here is a short example of my attempt, using two buttons:

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
introjsUI(), # must include in UI
mainPanel(
introBox(
  tableOutput("mtcars"),
  data.step = 1,
  data.intro = "This table is shown when button 1 is pressed"
),
introBox(
  actionButton("button1","Intro"),
  data.step = 1,
  data.intro = "This button is shown when button 2 is pressed"
), 
actionButton("button2","Intro2")
)))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$mtcars <- renderTable({
head(mtcars)
})
observeEvent(input$button1,
           introjs(session))
observeEvent(input$button2,
           introjs(session))
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above approach doesn't have anyway of linking the button to the separate "data.step1", which are the start of each tour. Tips and solutions gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to move all the data steps to a reactive element server side: https://gist.github.com/leonawicz/bd700264278fbaa1471929f14b0be1c4

It isn't in the documentation, but this example also shows how to change the tooltip position.